# Update Integrated in Build link during build pipeline not working

Tags: azure-pipelines

We have YAML based pipeline.
We are using multi repositories build, both repos are in ADO Git Repositories (not GitHub).

The "Automatically link work items included in this run" is checked, and the branch is set to "*" .
[enter image description here][1]

The pipeline identifies a work item is related:
[enter image description here][2]

However, no link is added of type "Integrated in build".

Any Suggestions?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVbKj.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL8nr.png

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I understand you would expect the pipeline triggered by a commit from the Azure Repos resources to add an `Integrated in build` link after the pipeline run is completed. So far, it is not possible if the commit is from the `repository resource` rather than from the `self` repo where the YAML definition is located.

I can reproduce the same behavior with the following simple YAML pipeline. The azure-pipelines.yml is from `REPO0`; the commit is pushed to `REPO1` and linked with a work item.

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
 repositories:
   - repository: REPOA
     type: git
     name: REPO1
     trigger:
       branches:
         include:
           - main
   - repository: REPOB
     type: git
     name: REPO2
     trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - main
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: REPOA
- checkout: REPOB
```

[image: CommitREPO1]

This commit will trigger the pipeline and we can see the `Related work item` in the run summary. However, the link `Integrated in build` is not added.

[image: RunSummary]

The behavior seems to be inconsistent with the statement in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/configure-pipelines-work-tracking?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#what-work-items-are-included-in-automatic-linking). For this, you may post your query [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) to share the issue with development engineers.